# Running a shell command on Android returns nothing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've been trying to get the output of a command for quite some hours now but with no result. Having this code:

```
val byteArry = ByteArray(1024)
 var Holder: String = ""
 try {
      val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/ls")
      val process = processBuilder.start()
      val  inputStream = process.getInputStream()
      while (inputStream.read(byteArry) !== -1) {
            Holder += String(byteArry)
      }
      inputStream.close()
      } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
      }
      println("Output: " + Holder)
```

I'm trying with different (kotlin and java) ways to receive some output from any command but I receive nothing. No errors either. Using the file explorer in Android Studio I can see that the ls is located in that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's an error happening. You can check for that by either setting `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream` (before `start()`) to get it to the given `inputStream` or simply getting a separate `InputStream` for errors by calling `Process.getErrorStream()`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to give you a definitive answer. Your current code is just trying to run a process that is located at `/system/bin/ls` (from working directory). If you're in fact trying to run `ls` for directory `/system/bin/`, you're going to want to send the directory as an argument to `ProcessBuilder`, as so:

```
  val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder("ls", "/system/bin/")
```

Comment: Wow passing the path separately actually solved the original issue! I've found more than 10 threads in SO about this and not a single one passes the executable like that. However... I'm receiving permission denied when trying to run the executable from the apps own files. The file already has chmod 777 and chmod +x. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm now able to run it. I just needed to chmod the files propery and use ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream as you suggested in order to see the error on the stdout. Thank you for your help